# How to get redirect_to to change host when using a path as a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, host

I'm redirecting in rails using a string like so:

```
path = "/blerg/blergs/blergs/blergs"

domain = "www.google.com"
```

So in the controller I'm redirect like this:

```
redirect_to path, :status => :found, :host => domain
```

The problem is the domain isn't changing, it's staying the same as the app's domain. How do redirect with the host param while using a string as the path?

The reason I'm doing this to avoid this security bug, the path has some params in it too:
http://brakemanscanner.org/docs/warning_types/redirect/

Comment: do I get it right: 1) you want to add the `:host` parameter (although it is not needed, because it is not changing) for security reasons. 2) your `:path` parameter is a string. 3) your existing `redirect_to` does not include the `:host` parameter accordingly. So you need another way of implementing the `redirect_to`adding the `:host` param

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/redirecting.rb#L84), when you use string paths, rails use request's domain.

one way to tell rails that url you are passing is in another domain, is to set the protocol:

```
     url = "http://#{another_domain_url}"
     redirect_to url
```

If you want to use a hash, you can move path to `:host` key (**not tested**):

```
     redirect_to :status => :found, :host => "#{domain}#{path}"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

```
redirect_to "http://#{domain}#{path}"
```

Comment: That's exactly what I don't want to do, that's why I said it and linked to the reason why.